# How to fix: The system cannot find the file specified - .reduce() in JS relevant

Tags: javascript, math

Write a function that takes in a positive parameter num and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single digit.

Eg: 939 -> 9*3*9 = 243 -> 2*4*3 = 24 -> 2*4 = 8 // Total: 3 times

I tried the code but it returns:

On Atom: "The system cannot find the file specified." // I use the script package

On repl.it: "tempoOne.reduce() is not a function"

`

```
let persistence = (num) => {

  let tempoOne, tempoTwo;
  let count = 0;
  let changeToString = num.toString();
  let numArray = changeToString.split('');
  var calculator = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator*currentValue;

  tempoOne = numArray;

  do {
    tempoOne = tempoOne.reduce(calculator);
    count++;
  } while (tempoOne/10 >= 0);
  return count;
}
console.log(persistence(939));`
```

Comment: in second `do` iteration you are using `reduce` in a number

Comment: i believed i have changed it to an array: `let numArray = changeToString.split('');`

Comment: yeah you did but when you reduce it, tempoOne turns out a number again

Comment: ohhhhhhhh!!! got it ^^ thank you so much. wow.!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to split the result of `reduce` again:

```js
let persistence = (num) => {
  let tempoOne, tempoTwo;
  let count = 0;
  let numArray = num.toString().split('');
  var calculator = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator * currentValue;
  var result;
  tempoOne = numArray;

  do {
    result = tempoOne.reduce(calculator);
    tempoOne = result.toString().split('');
    count++;
  } while (result / 10 > 1);
  return count;
}
console.log(persistence(939));
```

---

Without `result` variable:

```js
let persistence = (num) => {
  let tempoOne, tempoTwo;
  let count = 0;
  let numArray = num.toString().split('');
  var calculator = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator * currentValue;
  var result;
  tempoOne = numArray;

  do {
    tempoOne = tempoOne.reduce(calculator).toString().split('');
    count++;
  } while (tempoOne.length > 1);
  return count;
}
console.log(persistence(939));
```

Comment: Thank you so so much @shrys

Answer (score 1):

Bring your `tempoOne` back to `string` and `split` it over iterations:

```js
    let persistence = (num) => {
    
      let tempoOne, tempoTwo;
      let count = 0
      var calculator = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator*parseInt(currentValue);

    tempoOne = num;    

      do {
        tempoOne = tempoOne.toString().split('').reduce(calculator, 1);
        count++;
      } while (tempoOne/10 > 1);
      return count;
    }
    console.log(persistence(939));
```

I've noted few errors in your approach with can lead some errors:

1. when you `split()` a string, you'll get an array of strings, so you must parse it into int before multiplying it 'cause you don't want to multiply strings (added `parseInt` into your `reduce callback` and starting it with neutral multiply factor: `1`).
2. you don't have to `split` out of loop cause you want `tempoOne` to be a string inside loop to `split()` works properly (removed `split` outside loop and added into loop).

Comment: But have you tried your code yet ? Cuz i did and it returned undefined =)

Comment: @Marwin, sorry man, I didnt get other few errors at first glance, but I've just added it

Comment: oh my. I'm a JS newbie and this problem has taken me for days.Now it is solved . Thank you so so much

Comment: @Marvin great! besides accepting answers, you can either upvote if you find useful.